# Entity Framework 7 - multiple Where conditions, if boolean equals true

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm still learning and understanding fully Entity Framework, but working on a personal project to aim to increase that learning.

Currently I have a search function, which can search for Artist, Album or Title (or a combination of any 3).

To simplify how much code I'm adding here, I have an Angular UI which has checkboxes, which then pushes through to a Web API.  I've checked the model Web API side and the data being received is correct.

What I want to do is query the SQL table, in the table columns:

Column `[Artist]` contains `SearchTerm` when `Artist` is `true`

**OR**

Column `[Album]` contains `SearchTerm` when `Album` is `true`

**OR**

Column `[Title]` contains `SearchTerm` when `Title` is `true`

Output the resultant query set back to the Angular UI.

I have attempted this using the code below, but I think I'm narrowing down by the `Artist` first, then whatever is that trimmed down dataset, is then being filtered by `Album`, then finally `Title`, and therefore usually returns no records as the conditions remove potential search values which would be found using an OR condition.

**SearchModel.cs**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class SearchModel
    {
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool Artist {  get; set; }
        public bool Album { get; set; }
        public bool Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**SearchController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Project.Context;
using Project.Models;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SearchController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public SearchController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            this._db = db;
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TrackData>> SearchAll([FromBody] SearchModel searchData)
        {
            if (searchData == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("no data");
            }
            var query = _db.TrackData.AsQueryable();
            
            if (searchData.Artist)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Artist.Contains(searchData.SearchTerm));
            }
            if (searchData.Album)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.AlbumTitle.Contains(searchData.SearchTerm));
            }  
            if (searchData.Title)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchData.SearchTerm));
            }            
            return Ok(await query.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @TaoGómezGil yes it did, thank you - I wasn't aware of Predicate, the example shown was almost exactly what I needed, just a slight alteration to the EF part but works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tao Gómez Gil for providing the solution, I wasn't aware of Predicate, but this successfully resolved my problem.  The revised code for my Controller is below, should this help anyone else.

```
using LinqKit;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Project.Context;
using Project.Models;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SearchController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public SearchController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            this._db = db;
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TrackData>> SearchAll([FromBody] SearchModel searchData)
        {
            if (searchData == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("no data");
            }
            // Instantiate Predicate, with a data type of TrackData (which is the data model returned)
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<TrackData>();
            if (searchData.Artist)
            {
                // If searchData.Artist evaluates True, add the search term to the Or condition                
                predicate.Or(x => x.Artist.Contains(searchData.SearchTerm));
            }
            if (searchData.Album)
            {
                // If searchData.Album evaluates True, add the search term to the Or condition  
                predicate.Or(x => x.AlbumTitle.Contains(searchData.SearchTerm));
            }  
            if (searchData.Title)
            {
                // If searchData.Title evaluates True, add the search term to the Or condition  
                predicate.Or(x => x.Title.Contains(searchData.SearchTerm));
            }
            // And now perform the query, with the Predicate within the Where clause
            var query = _db.TrackData.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate);
            // Output resultant query set
            return Ok(await query.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
}
```